# NodeJs get request returns wrong data

Tags: node.js, post, get, request

Im building a 'man in the middle' type server. Users requests pages from my node server, my node server requests the pages from the origin server and cache's them for next time the page is requested.

I am currently trying to open a session on the origin server.

If I visit this url

www.originDomain.co.uk/ajax/login.php?username=user@emailHost.com&password=password

a session is successfully open and i get a response back (from the php script) saying logged in.

I cant seem to replicate this request in node.js I am using this code:

```
        var data = querystring.stringify({
           username: 'user@emailHost.com',
           password: 'password'
        });

        var options = {
            host: 'www.originDomain.co.uk',
            port: 80,
            path: '/ajax/login.php',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
            }
        };

        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log("body: " + chunk);
            });
        });

        req.write(data);
        req.end();
```

with this call i get a response (from the PHP script) saying "please enter a user name"

I am assuming that the query string is not being sent with the request as if you just visit www.originDomain.co.uk/ajax/login.php you get the message back "please enter a user name".

Please help, been trying to solve this for 3 hours now. Iv looked at the node documentation and iv searched forums but nothing seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to send your login credentials in the body of a `GET` request. Also to simplify your request processing you might want to look at using [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) rather than node's native `http.request`.

Example:

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://www.originDomain.co.uk/ajax/login.php',
  qs: {
    username: 'user@emailHost.com',
    password: 'password'
  }
};

request(options, function(err, resp, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

That said, to begin with I would be concerned about sending the user credentials as query params in a `GET` request.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback mate, unfortunately this dose work. I get no data back at all. I did try with post and NPM version of request originally but after 2 hours of failing i decided to try do it in a get request.

Comment: Are you using the `request` module? If so, are you getting an error response? Are `err` or `resp` populated?

Comment: Sadly not getting errors, the response returns ' please provide a user name'. 

If i visit this URL
www.originDomain.co.uk/ajax/login.php?
(without the query string) it also just returns ' please provide a user name' from the php script

Comment: I just used the postman plugin on chrome and if i put the user name and password in the params section it works. if i put it in headers it dosent. does that help you help me?

Comment: I guess I am confused. If you use the original URL in the question posted via simply entering it in a browser it works? But using the provided example with `request` doesn't?

Comment: yup thats correct, entering the that URL the browser works (i get login success and a session cookie). and yes using request dosent work.

Im feeling that in node the parameters arnt being added when the request is being sent. Thanks so much for the help i really appreciate it

Comment: There must be cookies stored on your browser that are providing some additional parameters. I would look at the request to see what is being sent from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
To be honest with you, no idea how this fixed my issue... but it did.

```
        var headers = {
          'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
          'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }

        // Configure the request
        var options = {
            url: 'http://www.originDomain.co.uk/ajax/login.php',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers,
            qs: {'username': 'user@domain.com', 'password':'password'}
        }

        // Start the request
        req(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                // Print out the response body
                console.log(body)
            }
        })
```

Comment: It appears you added a couple header params to my suggested answer. The site might be checking for content type.

Comment: I have marked your comment as accepetd. i think i was being stupid and missed out /ajax/login.php in the request url when i first tried this solution